# convert a list which has single elements and lists into a flat list

Tags: python, arrays, list

How would you convert a list like this :

```
["foo",["banana","apple"], "banana", ["peaches","grapes"]]
```

into

```
["foo","banana","apple", "banana", "peaches",'grapes"]
```

I tried:

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in regular_list for item in sublist]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Comment: The current dup is not the correct one; it is exactly what OP has tried.

Comment: the linked answer would work if all elements were a `list` type though

Comment: @fafl No, it is what OP has tried, which does not work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach using a nested `list` comprehension could be to check if each element is a `list`, and convert it to a list type otherwise:

```py
regular_list = ["foo",["banana","apple"], "banana", ["peaches","grapes"]]


flat_list = [item for sublist in regular_list
             for item in (sublist if isinstance(sublist, list) else [sublist])]

print(flat_list)
```

Result:

```
['foo', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'peaches', 'grapes']
```

Answer (score 4):

If the maximum depth of nesting is not too large, you can use recursion to flatten even deeper amount of nesting:

```py
def flatten(a):
    if not isinstance(a, list):
        yield a
        return
    for x in a:
        yield from flatten(x)

regular_list = ["foo",[[[["banana",[["apple"]]]]]], [[[["banana"]]]], ["peaches","grapes"]]
flat_list = list(flatten(regular_list))
print(flat_list)
```

Output

```py
['foo', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'peaches', 'grapes']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ["foo", ["banana", "apple"], "banana", ["peaches", "grapes"]]

ans = []
for el in arr:
    ans.extend(el) if isinstance(el, list) else ans.append(el)
ans
# ['foo', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'peaches', 'grapes']
```

Comment: `ans.extend(el) if isinstance(el, list) else ans.append(el)` doesn't evaluate to anything other than `None`, so using an expression is pointless, just use a regular if-else *statement* instead of an expression

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, why does it have to evaluate to anything if I haven't assigned it to a variable?